# Convertir JSON que contiene barra invertida utilizando C#

Tags: c#, json, .net

Les comento que estoy consumiendo un servicio REST de un tercero, cuando realizo el llamado este me devuelve un json, el problema es que el json viene de la siguiente forma:
(Aqui un fragmento del JSON)

```
"GetBookingResult": "{\"reserva\":{\"fecha_creacion\":{\"#text\":\"15FEB17\"},\"hora_creacion\":{\"#text\":\"2133\"},\"responsable\":{\"tipo_reserva\":\"WEBPAS\",\"cod_cia\":\"OB\",\"off_resp\":\"OBW101\"},\"localizador_resiber\":{\"#text\":\"P7S44\"}
```

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para consumir el servicio

```
public static Reserva getBooking(GetBookingRequest requestParams)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter requestWriter;

                string postData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(requestParams);

                var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://miUrl.svc/metodo") as HttpWebRequest;
                if (webRequest != null)
                {
                    webRequest.Method = "POST";
                    webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                    webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    //POST the data.
                    using (requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        requestWriter.Write(postData);
                    }
                }

                using (HttpWebResponse resp = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        throw new Exception(String.Format(
                        "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                        resp.StatusCode,
                        resp.StatusDescription));

                    Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
                    var resultado = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(resultado);

                    var str = resultado.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);

                    JToken token = JToken.Parse(str);
                    JObject o = JObject.Parse((string)token);


                    JObject response = o["reserva"] as JObject;
                    GetBookingResponse respuesta = response.ToObject<GetBookingResponse>();

                    return respuesta.reserva;
                }              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ocurrio un error obteniendo los datos de la reserva");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

al final lo que estoy intentando es obtener el elemento reserva del json que me devuelve el servicio y convertirlo a a un objeto de tipo Reserva que yo he creado en .NET

Comment: Creo que no logro comprender realmente la pregunta, ¿existe algún tema por la forma en que recibes la información?

Comment: Hola FLxtr, el problema se da al intentar convertir el string en formato json que me devuelve el servicio en a un objeto. 

var str = resultado.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
JToken token = JToken.Parse(str);

cuando intento convertirlo a un JToken o un JObject me genra el siguiente error:

{"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: r. Path 'GetBookingResult', line 1, position 23."}

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el error que te envía? Esto para saber más a detalle lo que se tendría que corregir y poder darte una respuesta más puntual :)

Comment: Si, el error es el siguiente: 
 {"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: r. Path 'GetBookingResult', line 1, position 23."} 

Se presenta justo al momento de intentar convertir el string en formato JSON a un JToken o a un JObject

Comment: Sugiero que agregues más detalles directamente a la pregunta, edítala poniendo el mensaje de error que te da, la línea en que se presenta el error y la definición de tu clase `GetBookingResponse`, para poder hacer un *match* con todos los elementos y poder comparar el json contra la definición de tu clase

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentan, no es el problema del codigo de parseo, sino mas bien del string que es un supuesto JSON. **Es invalido**, por lo menos el que colocas de ejemplo.

Antes que nada, en C# en cadenas el caracter \ es un caracter de escape, mas info aqui

- [String/Cadenas > Secuencias de escape de cadena](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences)

Este json que proporcionas si le quitamos los caracteres de escape \" reemplazando por " y probando online en un parseador de json

```
"GetBookingResult": "{\"reserva\":{\"fecha_creacion\":{\"#text\":\"15FEB17\"},\"hora_creacion\":{\"#text\":\"2133\"},\"responsable\":{\"tipo_reserva\":\"WEBPAS\",\"cod_cia\":\"OB\",\"off_resp\":\"OBW101\"},\"localizador_resiber\":{\"#text\":\"P7S44\"}
```

Esta mal armado, puedes probar

- https://jsoneditoronline.org/
- http://jsonparseronline.com/

Si ves queda algo asi
 - No comienza por un caracter {} o [] *objeto u array de objetos en json*

De comienzo ya podemos decir que esta mal armado el conjunto debe comenzar como un array o un objeto {}, Seria algo asi simple, para darle un vistazo

```
{"GetBookingResult":1}
```

Si es completo como deberia ser (sin el caracter escape para probar online)

```
 {"GetBookingResult": {"reserva":{"fecha_creacion":{"#text":"15FEB17"}, "hora_creacion":{"#text":"2133"}, "responsable":{"tipo_reserva":"WEBPAS","cod_cia":"OB","off_resp":"OBW101"},"localizador_resiber":{"#text":"P7S44"}}}}
```

[image: Ejemplo de parseo]

Pero por  eso no se si lo que te envia es un GetBookingResult completo, o es un variable de Request GetBookingResult que dentro tiene un string que es un json, Ya que esta luego de GetBookingResult: .... si parece un objeto JSON (aunque falta cerrar unas llaves al final)

Pero suponiendo que le puedes indicar al que te envia que lo envie correctamente con todo lo que te vamos proponiendo, aqui el codigo para parsear en un dymamic y leer cada parte del objeto json

```
 var jsonData =         "{\"GetBookingResult\": {\"reserva\":{\"fecha_creacion\":{\"#text\":\"15FEB17\"}, \"hora_creacion\":{\"#text\":\"2133\"}, \"responsable\":{\"tipo_reserva\":\"WEBPAS\",\"cod_cia\":\"OB\",\"off_resp\":\"OBW101\"},\"localizador_resiber\":{\"#text\":\"P7S44\"}}}}";

        dynamic demo = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonData);

        Console.WriteLine(demo.GetBookingResult);
        Console.WriteLine(demo.GetBookingResult.reserva);
        Console.WriteLine(demo.GetBookingResult.reserva.fecha_creacion);
        Console.WriteLine(demo.GetBookingResult.reserva.hora_creacion);
        Console.WriteLine(demo.GetBookingResult.reserva.responsable);

       Console.WriteLine(demo.GetBookingResult.reserva.localizador_resiber);
```

Answer (score 0):

¿en qué línea específica es que obtienes el error? supongo que no llegues a convertir al `JObject`.
En estos casos no necesitas hacer el `Replace`, lo que hago normalmente es lo siguiente:

`JObject obj = JObject.Parse(resultado);`

Donde `resultado` tiene el string devuelto por el servicio incluyendo los `\`.
Ya después conviertes a tu entidad de la manera que prefieras.

Comment: Hola mako, el error se da en esta linea:
JToken token = JToken.Parse(str); y el error que lanza es este: 
 {"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: r. Path 'GetBookingResult', line 1, position 23."}

Comment: Hola, y con esto que te dije de `JObject obj = JObject.Parse(resultado);` no resolviste?

Answer (score 0):

He estado viendo tu Json y lo primero decirte que esta bastante raramente formado. Para que te hagas una idea ese json para que pase un parseo de validacion debería ser así:

```
{"GetBookingResult": {"reserva":{"fecha_creacion":{"#text":"15FEB17"},"hora_creacion":{"#text":"2133"},"responsable":{"tipo_reserva":"WEBPAS","cod_cia":"OB","off_resp":"OBW101"},"localizador_resiber":{"#text":"P7S44"}}}}
```

Te sobran las \ eso ya lo tienes resuelto, pero ademas te falta un { al principio de todo, te faltan tres } al final de todo y te sobran unas " justo antes de {"reserva"}.

Cambiando eso ya deberias poder parsearlo a clase sin problema con Newtonsoft o con el propio de .Net y de ahi sacar los datos.

Adaptandolo a c# me sale esta estructura de clases

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Getbookingresult GetBookingResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class Getbookingresult
    {
        public Reserva reserva { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reserva
    {
        public Fecha_Creacion fecha_creacion { get; set; }
        public Hora_Creacion hora_creacion { get; set; }
        public Responsable responsable { get; set; }
        public Localizador_Resiber localizador_resiber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fecha_Creacion
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hora_Creacion
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Responsable
    {
        public string tipo_reserva { get; set; }
        public string cod_cia { get; set; }
        public string off_resp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Localizador_Resiber
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

¿Ese Json lo formas tu o te viene de algún lado ya hecho?